# Is empty set is a part/subset of some/any set from the point of view of set theory?

Tags: set-theory

Is empty set is a part/subset of some/any set from the point of view of set theory?

Comment: Are you asking if the empty set is part of a set? Or if the set that contains “nothing” is a set?

Comment: Define "nothing" (empty set?) "is part of" (member-of? subset-of?) and "something" in terms of set theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an empty set is considered a subset of other sets.

A particular example is that a [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) (the set of all subsets) always includes the empty set.

Per Wikipedia:

> In mathematics, the power set (or powerset) of a set S is the set of
> all subsets of S, including the empty set and S itself.